# Return Y/N value for whether a plotted point is within x metres of any plotted points within a list (mapping exercise)

Tags: r

I have a number of UK postcodes with associated lat/long values. What I am required to do is compare the lat/long value points from 'ListA' against another list 'ListB' of lat/long values and return a Y/N value in ListA for each row depending on whether they are within 2,500 metres of any lat/long value within ListB.

So let's say I was comparing these two postcodes only, to demonstrate principle (in truth both datasets have hundreds of postcodes):

ListA

| Postcode | Lat | Long |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PE36 6LQ | 52.97426 | 0.5526301 |
| NR23 1DR | 52.97246 | 0.8495693 |

And the source dataset is:

ListB

| Postcode | Lat | Long |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PE36 6LD | 52.9565 | 0.55366 |
| RM18 8PB | 52.97246 | 0.8495693 |

End result should be:

| Postcode | Lat | Long | Within2500m |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PE36 6LD | 52.9565 | 0.55366 | Y |
| RM18 8PB | 52.97246 | 0.8495693 | N |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert the data to spatial features and calculate the nearest distances using the `sf` package. In your example, both points in listA are within 2500m of a point in listB.

```
#libraries
library(data.table)
library(sf)

#data
dt1 <- data.table(Postcode = c("PE36 6LQ", "NR23 1DR"), Lat = c(52.97426, 52.97246), Lon = c(0.5526301, 0.8495693))
dt2 <- data.table(Postcode = c("PE36 6LD", "RM18 8PB"), Lat = c(52.9565, 52.97246), Lon = c(0.55366, 0.8495693))

#convert to spatial features
dt1.sf <- st_as_sf(dt1, coords = c("Lon", "Lat"), crs = st_crs(4326))
dt2.sf <- st_as_sf(dt2, coords = c("Lon", "Lat"), crs = st_crs(4326))

#check which points are most distant
nearest <- st_nearest_feature(dt1.sf, dt2.sf)

#add nearest distances
dt1[, nearest_dist := as.numeric(st_distance(dt1.sf, dt2.sf[nearest,], by_element = TRUE))]
dt1[nearest_dist < 2500, Within2500m := "Y"]
dt1[nearest_dist >= 2500, Within2500m := "N"]
```

gives

```
dt1
   Postcode      Lat       Lon nearest_dist Within2500m
1: PE36 6LQ 52.97426 0.5526301     1976.029           Y
2: NR23 1DR 52.97246 0.8495693        0.000           Y
```